How can I programmatically open the Advanced options page for a given UWP application in the Windows Settings application from the outside?

The Apps > Installed apps page of the Windows Settings application lists all applications that were either installed via the Microsoft Store application or via the winget.exe CLI.
Among them, those that are UWP applications have application-specific settings, which can be viewed and managed interactively by clicking on the … symbol next to an application of interest and selecting Advanced options.

Can such an application-specific settings page be opened directly, programmatically for a given UWP application, using an URI, from a PowerShell script?

What I've tried:
The relevant section of "Launch the Windows Settings app" states (emphasis added):

ms-settings:appsfeatures-app (Reset, manage add-on & downloadable content, etc. for the app)
To access this page with a URI, use the ms-settings:appsfeatures-app URI and pass an optional parameter of the package family name of the app.

This suggests that a query string should be appended to the ms-settings:appsfeatures-app URI in order to directly open a given app's features page (which in the GUI of the Settings app is termed Advanced options when you click on the … menu of an app):

A given app's package family name can be obtained as follows, using the Microsoft Calculator application as an example:
# -> 'Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe'
(Get-AppxPackage *Calculator*).PackageFamilyName


However, it isn't clear what the exact query-string parameter name should be.


The following does not work:
# !! DOESN'T WORK: opens the Apps > Installed apps overview page, 
# !! not the app-specific page.
# !! That is, it acts the same as: Start-Process ms-settings:appsfeatures
# ?? What is the exact format of the query string?
Start-Process ms-settings:appsfeatures-app?package-family-name=Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe

Note:

Judging by GitHub docs issue #3688, which as of this writing is awaiting official feedback, it isn't clear whether this is actually supported from outside a given app.

From inside an UWP application, launching ms-settings:appsfeatures-app - without a query string - is apparently enough to open the page of interest, as implied both by the linked GitHub issue and this related question (note that the latter is explicitly about launching the settings page from inside an UWP application, for that same application).


Questions:

Can someone answer definitely whether or not opening such an app-specific settings page by URI from outside the targeted application is supported?

Note: The fact that you can directly invoke the application-specific settings page for a given application via its entry in the Start Menu (by right-clicking on the entry and selecting App settings) implies that there is some way to do this - but this doesn't necessarily mean that the URI method is supported or even that the method used is a public API.


If so, what is the exact query-string format?

If not, is there another, officially supported method?


